# ASP.NET Core docs show unfamiliar usage of the ? operator. What does it mean?

Tags: c#, boolean, conditional-statements

The ASP.NET Core minimal API [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#iresult-return-values) show syntax similar to the following:

```
db.Todos.Find(id)
is Todo todo
    ? Results.Ok(todo)
    : Results.NotFound());
```

I believe this is a use case of the `?` operator which is documented in the main C# [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). However, these docs only show the following format:

```
condition ? consequent : alternative
```

in which `condition` must evaluate to a boolean.

The `is` keyword allows checking whether a particular variable has a certain type, so something like `db.Todos.Find(id) is Todo` should be sufficient.

However, they also introduce a variable `todo`, which is not being declared anywhere prior to this statement, and which they appear to pass as an argument to `Results.Ok`

I'm confused now. What does the addition of `todo` mean. Where is it documented that a variable can be included *after* `condition`? If it is not documented, then why not?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#type-tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s a typesafe [pattern matching cast.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/safely-cast-using-pattern-matching-is-and-as-operators)

So the variable ‘todo’ is verifiably a non-null Todo.